# How to set up 2 or more trains running on the same track?

Tags: openttd

How do you set up multiple trains running on the same track, using sideline rails (I don't know what the proper terminology for those sections of railroad is)? What signals would you use and how?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you call a sideline rail?  What's it's purpose?

Comment: There's a few different ways of doing it, which type of signals are you most comfortable using?

Comment: The OpenTTD Wiki has a lot of interesting information: https://wiki.openttd.org/Signals

Answer (score 7):

By "sideline rail", I assume you mean a passing loop.  The easiest way to do it is like this:

[image]

The passing section is as long as the longest train on the track, plus one tile for the signal.  One-way path-based signals at the exits from the passing loop ensure that each section of track has only one train on it.  You can extend this layout to handle more trains by adding more passing loops: one loop for each train.

Depending on timing, you may occasionally have two trains in the section with the depot: one in the station, and one heading to or from the depot.  This isn't a safety problem: the path-based signaling system ensures that only one of the two trains is moving at a time.